# How to Create Adaptors for Custom Widgets in Glade?

Tags: gtk3, glade, pygobject

I have trouble getting custom widgets to work in Glade. Let's say I have a custom widget consisting of a stack in a frame.

```
class FramedStack(Gtk.Misc):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = Gtk.Frame()
        self.stack = Gtk.Stack()
        self.frame.add(self.stack)
```

I can add this to the Glade catalogue and it works fine. But now I want to modify the widgets behaviour in Glade. But as soon as I define an adaptor

```
class FramedStackAdaptor():
    def do_post_create(self, w, reason):
        pass #something
```

and modify the line in the catalogue, so that Glade knows about the adaptor

```
<glade-widget-class title="FramedStack" name="FramedStack" adaptor="FramedStackAdaptor"/>
```

I get a GladeUI warning

```
GladeUI-WARNING **: Failed to get FramedStack's adaptor FramedStackAdaptor.
```

The class definition is in the same file as the definition of the custom widget. I am assuming that FramedStackAdaptor should inherit a Glade Adaptor class, but I can't figure out whether there are such classes. So my question is: *How do I correctly define an adaptor for my custom widget?*

Answer (score 0):

```
class FramedStackAdaptor(Gladeui.WidgetAdaptor):
    def post_create(w, reason):
        pass #something
```

Should get you started